# string.Format and string adding spaces

Tags: c#

With both `string.Format` and using string concatenation is adding spaces in my string, which is in turn making my Test methods fail.
Here is my `ToString()` method:

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("First name: {0}, Last name: {1}, Age: {2}", FirstName, LastName, Age);

    }//end of ToString()
```

I also tried this and got the same output:

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        return "First name: " + FirstName  + ", Last name: " + LastName + ", Age: " + Age;

    }//end of ToString()
```

There is no space after the place holder, before the comma but when run this is the output:

```
First name: Jen , Last name: Doe , Age: 26
```

It puts a space after the placeholder, Why is this? how do I stop it

Comment: Are you sure that this is not simply a case of all the names having an extra space at end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FirstName.Trim()
```

The variables might contain spaces.

Comment: You know I was already using Trim() so at first I thought "no way I am trimming the whitespace, but then ... I looked at the implicit operator and realized when looping over the string it was adding the whitespace. duh?